# What scope/permissions do I need to get RoleAssignments via the rest api?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, oauth, role-assignment, azureadapps

I am using rest API role assignment for SharePoint Online with Oauth2.0 to fetch advanced permissions. But, I cannot give Full Control Scope to my Application. Is there any other way where I can get permissions given to folders with read only scope.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, only full control permissions can get  role assignments with rest api.

So you have to give Full Control Scope to your app.

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web/list" Right="FullControl"/>
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl"/>
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Comment: Thanks .Is there any minimum permissions set which we can use or any other alternate API?

Comment: May be you could use graph api to get permissions of folders: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/permission-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: The minimum permissions of the app you need to give: Files.Read.All, Files.ReadWrite.All, Sites.Read.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All

Comment: I need advanced permissions which does not come in graph API. So is there any other API in graph where I can get advanced permissions.

Comment: I have updated question with set of permissions which are not visible by graph API.